# How to merge HashRef in Moose attribute writer?

Tags: perl, moose

Having a simple example code

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

package My;
use Moose;
use Method::Signatures::Simple;
has 'result' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub{{}},
    clearer => 'clear_result'
);

method run {
    $self->clear_result;                 #clearing the result
    $self->result( $self->run_part1 );
    $self->do_something;
    $self->result( $self->run_part3 );   #need merge
}

method do_something {
    $self->result( $self->run_part2 );   #need merge
}

method run_part1 { return { aaa => 'aaa' } }
method run_part2 { return { bbb => 'bbb' } }
method run_part3 { return { ccc => 'ccc' } }

package main;
my $p = My->new;
say Dumper $p->run;
```

the result (ofcourse) is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ccc' => 'ccc'
        };
```

I want the result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'aaa' => 'aaa'
          'bbb' => 'bbb'
          'ccc' => 'ccc'
        };
```

so, the question is - how to merge the `$self->result` HashRef when setting it?

Yes, i can add new method `add_result` like:

```
method add_result($hr) {
    use Hash::Merge::Simple qw(merge);
    $self->result( merge $self->result, $hr );
}
```

and *change everywhere* in my code the `$self->result` to `$self->add_result` but wonder if there is another solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has 'result' => (
    acccessor => '_result',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub{{}},
    clearer => 'clear_result'
);

sub result {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) {
        my ($hr) = @_;
        return $self->_result( ... merged hash ...);
    } else {
        return $self->_result();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can also use `handles => { result => sub { ... } }` if you want to have the accessor's definition within the `has`.